# Why does Replay method prevent Observable collection from completing?

Tags: c#, roslyn, rx.net

I have a slow running task to execute on a list of items.
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Processing should start immediately
2. Max of N Concurrent tasks
3. Task should only be run once per item
4. All subscribers should see all results (regardless of when they subscribe)

This was my prototype - It works as expected (LinqPad)

```
async Task Main()
{
     int throttle = 3;

    var result =
        Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(n => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomething(n)))
        .Merge(throttle)
        .Replay();

    Task.Run(async () => await result);
    Util.KeepRunning();
}

public async Task DoSomething(int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting {n}");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"Ending {n}");
}
```

This is my actual code:

```
    sln.Projects = result
        .Projects
        .ToObservable() //Appears to be unnecessary
        .Select(p => Observable.FromAsync(() => projectLoader.Load(p, sln)))
        .Merge(_maxConcurrent)
        .Replay(); 

     await sln.Projects; //Hangs forever if Replay is used
```

"result" is a Microsoft.CodeAnalysisSolution

I've tried several variations-
    Projects.ToList, With ToObservable and Without
    Replaced project loader with a dummy load
    Ran with and without _maxConcurrent

This code hangs forever at the await and I can't seem to see what is functionally different than the prototype.

If I remove the Replay the code runs as expected but gets hit for every subscriber.

Does anyone have an idea as to how this code is different and why the Replay method affects execution like this?

I'm starting to suspect that it has to be an issue with the subscribers - but it isn't something I can easily extract at the moment to validate.

Here is the original code that does work (but doesn't throttle)

```
    sln.Projects = result.Projects
        .Select(p => projectLoader.Load(p, sln))
        .ToList()
        .Select(p => p.ToObservable())
        .Merge();
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the prototype and your actual use of the code is the way you store the observable. In your prototype it's stored as a local variable, but in your production code you persist it inside the `sln` object.

To be able to replay all the signals in the observable for future subscribers, it can't complete. I think the reason it works with local variable has something to do with local scope, but I haven't dug into that.

If you run the following in Linqpad, you'll see that storing the observable in an object changes the behavior.

```
async Task Main()
{
     int throttle = 3;
    var container = new Container();

    container.Results =
        Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
            .ToObservable()
            .Select(n => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomething(n)))
            .Merge(throttle)
            .Replay();

    var res = await container.Results;

    res.Dump("Res");
}

public async Task DoSomething(int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting {n}");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"Ending {n}");
}

public class Container
{
    public IObservable<Unit> Results { get; set; }
}
```

`Replay()` returns an `IConnectableObservable`, to make this observable return values you have to call `Connect()` on it. Doing this made the above code work for me:

```
async Task Main()
{
     int throttle = 3;
    var container = new Container();

    container.Results =
        Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(n => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoSomething(n)))
        .Merge(throttle)
        .Replay();

    container.Results.Connect();

    (await container.Results).Dump("1");
    (await container.Results).Dump("2");
}

public async Task DoSomething(int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Starting {n}");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine($"Ending {n}");
}

public class Container
{
    public IConnectableObservable<Unit> Results { get; set; }
}
```